# PHP Crash WinCache IIS 7.5

Tags: php, crash, wincache

- PHP 5.6
- IIS 7.5
- WINCACHE 1.3.6.3

Sometimes one website on my server crash and in event viewer I see that error:

```
Faulting application name: php-cgi.exe, version: 5.6.0.0, time stamp: 0x53fe294e
Faulting module name: php_wincache.dll, version: 1.3.6.3, time stamp: 0x544ad12f
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00012fe7
Faulting process id: 0x1460
Faulting application start time: 0x01d048896ff45425
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php-cgi.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\php_wincache.dll
Report Id: a2371547-b488-11e4-ad72-00155d324103
```

I won't disable wincache, it's very helpful, I'd like to decode that Fault offset, how can I do that?

Comment: Do you have a crash dump file for php-cgi.exe?  That would be the best way to investigate the failure.

Comment: i haven't any dump, only that info in event viewer :\

Comment: Can you try updating wincache to 2.0.0.8 ?

Comment: I'll try.
I just discover than people who prepared the server disabled Windows Update. So I'll execute all 120 updates (maybe dll will be) all and monitor for a few days if it crashes again.
Thanks Evan

Comment: upgrade wincache, it seems to be bug in older version.

Comment: Can you see here(https://forums.iis.net/t/1210919.aspx?HTTP+500+errors+and+Wincache+crashes+Request+for+Info) and you may uninstall the old one and install updated.

Answer (score 1):

Running wincache on IIS is just troublesome, I've never had any luck of getting it to work without some sort of issue/crash. I suggest you update to PHP 7 for a few reasons.

- PHP 7 is officially supported for windows 64bit
- You don't need wincache with PHP 7
- PHP 5.6 is only supported with security fixes
- End of life is 1 Jan 2019 ([Currently Supported Versions](http://php.net/supported-versions.php))